# External Wordpress Blog Feed display

Tags: wordpress, feed

Working to display Blog lists of external wordpress blog.
There is a PHP issue in the code, it only shows only one

```
  add_shortcode( 'first', 'foobar_func' );

  function foobar_func( $atts ){

    $feed = fetch_feed( 'https://wordpress.org/news/feed/' );

    if (!is_wp_error($feed)):
      $maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity(3);
      $rss_items = $feed->get_items(CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0, $maxitems);
    endif;

    if ($maxitems == 0) {
      return '<li>No items.</li>';
    } else foreach ( $rss_items as $item )  {
      $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $item->get_content(), $matches);
      $first_img = $matches [1][0];
      $testts = esc_html($item->get_title());
    }
    return $testts;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried basic debugging?

Comment: Yes I did. Something mess up with "foreach"

Comment: Why do you have `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` ? Set it to 0 like the docs say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. Notice `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` has been swapped for `0`.

```
  add_shortcode( 'first', 'foobar_func' );

  function foobar_func( $atts ){

    $feed = fetch_feed( 'https://wordpress.org/news/feed/' );

    if (!is_wp_error($feed)):
      $maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity(3);
      $rss_items = $feed->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    endif;

    if ($maxitems == 0) {
      return '<li>No items.</li>';
    } else foreach ( $rss_items as $item )  {
      $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $item->get_content(), $matches);
      $first_img = $matches [1][0];
      $testts = esc_html($item->get_title());
    }
    return $testts;
  }
```

Comment: It is working :) but it outputs only one. $maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity(3); - it should be 3

Comment: Try replace $maxitems for `5` instead?